# Calling methods within methods ruby

Tags: ruby, methods

I'm trying to figure out how to call methods inside methods in ruby.

Here's my code:

```
def testNegative number 
  if number < 0  # No negative numbers.
    return 'Please enter a number that isn\'t negative.'
  end
end

def testIfZero number
  if number == 0
    return 'zero'
  end
end

def englishNumber number
  testNegative(number) 
  testIfZero(number) 
end

puts englishNumber -1
puts englishNumber 0
```

Currently, the output I'm getting is an empty line and then "zero". I was wondering why I don't see "Please enter a number that isn't negative" as the output of put englishNumber -1. How can I fix things so that "Please enter a number that isn't negative" is returned and the programs ends?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll use underscores instead of camel case in my answer, because that is what people usually do for Ruby methods.

Your code doesn't work right now because `test_negative` is returning a value but `english_number` is not doing anything with the value.  You could change `english_number` to:

```
def english_number(number)
  test_negative(number) or test_if_zero(number)
end
```

That way if `test_negative` returns a non-nil and non-false value, then `english_number` will use that as its return value and not bother running `test_if_zero`.

Later, if you need to add more lines of code to `english_number`, you can do it like this:

```
def english_number(number)
  error_message = test_negative(number) || test_if_zero(number)
  return error_message if error_message

  # More lines of code here
end
```

By the way, it sounds like you might actually want to use exceptions.  When you raise an exception, the program will end and the exception message will be printed to the user unless you do something to catch and handle the exception.  I would change `test_negative` to:

```
def test_negative(number)
  if number < 0  # No negative numbers.
    raise 'Please enter a number that isn\'t negative.'
  end
end
```

Comment: Adding the keyword raise doesn't work for me since I don't want the program to end on the first call of english number. The solution of adding or works for now, but once that's not longer the last line of my code it'll just be ignored like the first line is the way I have things now.

Comment: Gwater17: I edited my answer to show how you could add more lines of code to `english_number`.  However, I still left the mention of exceptions there for the benefit of future readers.

Answer (score 0):

Your code

```
def englishNumber number
  testNegative(number) 
  testIfZero(number) 
end
```

calls first `testNegative(number)` and ignores the result.

Then it calls `testIfZero(number)` and returns the result to the caller.

For `englishNumber -1` the result of `testIfZero(number)`is nil and `puts`writes an empty line.

For `englishNumber 0` you get the expected string `'zero'`.

---

If you need a the results as alternative you must return the results with an `or` condition (or `||`).

A complete example:

```
def testNegative number 
  if number < 0  # No negative numbers.
    return 'Please enter a number that isn\'t negative.'
  end
end

def testIfZero number
  if number == 0
    return 'zero'
  end
end

def englishNumber number
  testNegative(number) or testIfZero(number) 
end

puts englishNumber -1
puts englishNumber 0
```

or with an alternate syntax:

```
def testNegative number 
    return 'Please enter a number that isn\'t negative.' if number < 0  # No negative numbers.
end

def testIfZero number
  return 'zero' if number == 0
end

def englishNumber number
  testNegative(number) ||  testIfZero(number) 
end

puts englishNumber -1
puts englishNumber 0
```

I'm not sure if I understand your comments correct, but maybe you are looking for a solution like this:

```
def testNegative number 
    puts 'Please enter a number that isn\'t negative.' if number < 0  # No negative numbers.
end

def testIfZero number
  puts 'zero' if number == 0
end

def englishNumber number
  testNegative(number) 
  testIfZero(number) 
end

englishNumber -1
englishNumber 0
```

The `puts` command can also be used inside the methods, you don't need to return a result.

---

Remark outside the scope of the question: The usage of a method call inside a method is not the simplest solution (but I think you want to check the usage of method calls).

I would use:

```
def english_number number

  if number < 0  # No negative numbers.
    return 'Please enter a number that isn\'t negative.'
  elsif number == 0
    return 'zero'
  end
end
```

Comment: I get that. I just want to find a way that the result of the first line isn't ignored. Is there anything I can do?

Comment: The `test_negative(number) or test_if_zero(number) ` in [Davids Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36850553/676874) should answer your quesion.

Comment: The problem with that solution is it only answers my problem if I end the program there. Once `test_negative(number) or test_if_zero(number) ` is no longer the last line of the program the results of each of those functions are ignored.